# Apache royale read file javascript in project

Tags: javascript, apache, apache-royale

Good morning, I have a project with apache royale jewel at the moment I have a problem since I need to access js functions
I have on the route
src \ resources 
jewel-index-template.html
jsencrypt.js
Inside the jewel-index-template.html add some functions that consume jsencrypt.js but at the moment from my action script function I cannot access them you have an example of how to do it.
Additional I already subscribed and I already share my problem in the forum

Comment: your question is just not clear.

Comment: also, if the forum you refer is the Apache Royale mailing list, I didn't saw your question there